# Wrong printing of a bash output on python

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to automatize some processes (for a RNA-seq) from bash with a python program, the first step would be passing the files from *.fastq like this

```
Demo_T3_L001_R1.fastq  Demo_T3_L002_R1.fastq  Demo_T3_L003_R1.fastq  Demo_T3_L004_R1.fastq
Demo_T3_L001_R2.fastq  Demo_T3_L002_R2.fastq  Demo_T3_L003_R2.fastq  Demo_T3_L004_R2.fastq
```

(the content of the files is irrelevant for my problem, but I can copy them if needed)

to *.fasta, like this:

```
Demo_T3_L001_R1.fasta  Demo_T3_L002_R1.fasta  Demo_T3_L003_R1.fasta  Demo_T3_L004_R1.fasta
Demo_T3_L001_R2.fasta  Demo_T3_L002_R2.fasta  Demo_T3_L003_R2.fasta  Demo_T3_L004_R2.fasta
```

and I have this script:

```
import sys
import os
from os import listdir
from  os.path import isfile, join
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

mypath = '/home/Python_test'
## Read only *.fastq files ##
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f)) if 
f.endswith('.fastq')]
print("There are:", len(onlyfiles), "files.")
## Loop between the files found ##
for num in range (0,len(onlyfiles)):
    ## Command to do ##
    cmd_input = ('sed','-n','1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p',onlyfiles[num])
    ## Create names for otput files ##
    cmd_output = onlyfiles[num].replace('fastq','fasta')
    ## Open file ##
    sys.stdout = open(cmd_output, 'w')
    ## Print in file ##
    print(call(cmd_input))
```

But my problem is that the print appears on the terminal and all the files have only a '0' after running the script, like this

```
>>head *.fasta

==> Demo_T3_L001_R1.fasta <==
0

==> Demo_T3_L001_R2.fasta <==
0

==> Demo_T3_L002_R1.fasta <==
0

==> Demo_T3_L002_R2.fasta <==
0

==> Demo_T3_L003_R1.fasta <==
0

==> Demo_T3_L003_R2.fasta <==
0

==> Demo_T3_L004_R1.fasta <==
0

==> Demo_T3_L004_R2.fasta <==
0
```

I tried with:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd_input, stdout = cmd_output)
```

and with subprocess.call, but both with error: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'.

So I'm asking how to write the output correctly in the corresponding file, because I can't figure it out.
I believe the printing error is because the call happens in the terminal and the print doesn't have a clear input, so assumes a '0' as output, which it writes into the file, but it's just an assumption.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

From the documentation of [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

The return code is `0` (success) so that's what you're printing. If you want to get the command's output instead, use the other function.

Comment: Chaged it to `fasta_data = subprocess.check_output(['sed','-n','1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p',onlyfiles[num]], universal_newlines=True)` and it works just as I wanted. Thanks for the heads up, the `universal_newlines=False` as default was my other problem.